# NSWindow with very huge usage of CPU over 120% while opening

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, instruments, cpu-usage, nswindow

I'm using https://github.com/obolton/OBMenuBarWindow to create my application and face a problem with the performance. When i open my `NSWindow : OBMenuBarWindow` with clicking on the NSStatusItem, there is no problems. But when i click on it again to close the window, the CPU usage does start to increase very fast (over 120%). Open the window again and the CPU usage will be normal (0%). And these occur every time while opening and closing the window. I tried to debug also with Instruments but can not resolve this problem. What is going wrong with my coding? Here is my code snippet:

```
@interface MainWindowController : NSWindowController
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat arrowWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat arrowHeight;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet TableController *tableController;
@property IBOutlet OBMenuBarWindow *window;
@end

@implementation MainWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    self.window.menuBarIcon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"paperclipblack"];
    self.window.highlightedMenuBarIcon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"paperclipwhite"];
    self.window.title = @"App";
    self.window.hasMenuBarIcon = YES;
    self.window.attachedToMenuBar = YES;
    self.window.isDetachable = YES;
    self.arrowWidth = 20;
    self.arrowHeight = 10;
}

- (void)setArrowWidth:(CGFloat)width {
    self.window.arrowSize = NSMakeSize(width, self.window.arrowSize.height);
}

- (void)setArrowHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    self.window.arrowSize = NSMakeSize(self.window.arrowSize.width, height);
}


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong) MainWindowController *mainWindowController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    _mainWindowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindowController"];
    [_mainWindowController showWindow:nil];
}

@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with NSWindow instead of OBMenuBarWindow do the same . So you can figure it out its a NSWindow problem or issue in OBMenuBarWindow.